# How to check for DOM heights AFTER form loaded async data?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to apply a shadow only if my form's footer (containing action buttons) is in sticky mode.

Since ::sticky pseudo-class does not exist, i did it in TS.

I managed to make the element sticky with `position: sticky; bottom: 0`, then applying box-shadow on border-top with :

> [class.top-shadow]="isSticky" // in template

> .top-shadow {
> box-shadow: 0px -13px 10px -10px rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
> } // in CSS

and in component.ts

```
  @ViewChild('actionButtons') actionButtonsGroup!: ElementRef;
  isSticky = document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight;

  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAsyncData().subscribe((payload) => {
      this.form.patchValue(payload);
    });
  }

  ...

  // Hack to simulate the CSS state :sticky since it does not exist yet
  // to add a shadow when the actionButtonsGroup element becomes sticky
  @HostListener('window:scroll')
  onWindowScroll() {
    const elt = this.actionButtonsGroup.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement;
    const eltRect = elt.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.isSticky = document.body.clientHeight === Math.ceil(eltRect.bottom);
  }
```

This works perfectly on scrolling, **but it fails on init.**

My tests showed that isSticky is resolved BEFORE the form has finished to patchValue from the async request, which results in wrong heights to check isSticky (always false, scrollHeight = body height)

So i tried to trigger onWindowScroll calculations with :

```
// in ngOnInit
  this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.onWindowScroll());
  this.form.valueChanges.subscribe({ complete: () => this.onWindowScroll() });

  // No change, isSicky still always false...
```

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.onWindowScroll(); // Error: this.actionButtonsGroup is not initialized ...
  }
```

```
  // Triggered 3 times BEFORE request is subscribed and form patched, then 3 times again after
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.onWindowScroll(); // Works but Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
  }
```

What am i missing in this last solution to avoid the error ?

Or maybe someone has a better idea to initialize `isSticky` properly ?

PS: i don't want any solution based on dirty setTimeout

EDIT: i managed to implement a [solution based on intersectionObserver](https://codesandbox.io/s/sticky-footer-intersectionobserver-641hme?file=/src/index.js) Thanks for the blog link @TotallyNewb

Comment: The DOM won't be ready in ngOnInit. You may need to move your subscription to AfterViewInit

Comment: You might want to play around with [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver). A very nice case, very similar to yours, can be found in [this](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/sticky-headers/) blog post.

Comment: This blog is exactly what i needed, even better than my current implementation !
Thanks @TotallyNewb